# Mirror image along a custom axis (like shadow under the car)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is there any way I can mirror an image along a custom axis to generate an image like below if given a transparent image like It custom axis that passes through the bottom-most points of the tires. And map every point of the car onto the bottom through the axis. [image]

[image]

Comment: that's not a "custom" axis. to create that picture, you need more than 2D data. the reflection on the floor requires 3D information, at the very least another view from a specific viewpoint relative to the shiny floor and the given camera view.

Comment: It custom axis that passes through the bottom-most points of the tires. And map every point of the car onto the bottom through the axis. Shadow is the custom axis.

Comment: Please re-open this question.

Comment: I repeat, this **can't** be done as a 2D operation from a single image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.flip`

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("car.png")

flipcode = 0  # 0: along x axis, 1: along y axis, -1: along both x and y axes
flipped_img = cv2.flip(img, flipcode)

cv2.imshow("car", img)
cv2.imshow("flipped_car", flipped_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I know this is for flipping along the x or y-axis but I want to flip the image along the custom axis.